# Mostrar sólo los datos que yo quiero en un Adapter

Tags: java, android

Lo que pasa es que necesito mostrar únicamente los datos del objeto que clickeo en el adapter, pero en mi caso muestra los datos de todos los objetos que existen en la lista.

Este es un ejemplo:

Yo puedo elegir entre Telefónica y VTR, sin embargo al elegir Telefónica o VTR siempre me muestra la información de los dos. Los datos "Caja y Caja1" son de Telefónica, y los datos "Caja2 y Caja4" son de VTR. Lo que intento hacer es que cuando elija VTR me muestre solamente "Caja2 y Caja4" y cuando elija Telefónica, sólo me muestre "Caja y Caja1"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi Adapter

```
public class AdapterTipoAtencion extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTipoAtencion.TipoAtencionViewHolder> {

    List<Usuario> usuarios;
    private Context context;

    private String tap1, tap2, tap3, tap4, tap5, retap1, retap2, retap3, retap4, retap5;
    private TextView textviewtipoatencion1, textviewtipoatencion2, textviewtipoatencion3,
            textviewtipoatencion4, textviewtipoatencion5;
    private View viewtipoatencion1, viewtipoatencion2, viewtipoatencion3, viewtipoatencion4, viewtipoatencion5;
    private String País, Ciudad, TipodeEmpresa, EmpresaUser, EmpresaUid, Logo;
    private String pais, ciudad, tipodeempresa, empresauser, empresauid, logo;
    private Double Latitude, Longitude, lat, lng;

    public AdapterTipoAtencion(List<Usuario> usuarios, String País, String Ciudad,
                               String TipodeEmpresa, String EmpresaUser, String EmpresaUid, String Logo,
                               Double Latitude, Double Longitude) {
        this.usuarios = usuarios;
        this.País = País;
        this.Ciudad = Ciudad;
        this.TipodeEmpresa = TipodeEmpresa;
        this.EmpresaUser = EmpresaUser;
        this.EmpresaUid = EmpresaUid;
        this.Logo = Logo;
        this.Latitude = Latitude;
        this.Longitude = Longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public TipoAtencionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.adaptertipoatencion_row_recycler, parent, false);
        TipoAtencionViewHolder holder = new TipoAtencionViewHolder(v);

        context = v.getContext();

        textviewtipoatencion1 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion1);
        viewtipoatencion1 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion1);
        textviewtipoatencion2 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion2);
        viewtipoatencion2 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion2);
        textviewtipoatencion3 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion3);
        viewtipoatencion3 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion3);
        textviewtipoatencion4 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion4);
        viewtipoatencion4 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion4);
        textviewtipoatencion5 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion5);
        viewtipoatencion5 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion5);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TipoAtencionViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Usuario usuario = usuarios.get(position);
        tap1 = usuario.getTipoAtencion1();
        tap2 = usuario.getTipoAtencion2();
        tap3 = usuario.getTipoAtencion3();
        tap4 = usuario.getTipoAtencion4();
        tap5 = usuario.getTipoAtencion5();

        pais = País;
        ciudad = Ciudad;
        tipodeempresa = TipodeEmpresa;
        empresauser = EmpresaUser;
        empresauid = EmpresaUid;
        logo = Logo;
        lat = Latitude;
        lng = Longitude;

        if (tap1.equals("no contiene")) {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.viewtipoatencion1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion1.setText(tap1);
            retap1 = holder.textviewtipoatencion1.getText().toString();
        }

        if (tap2.equals("no contiene")) {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.viewtipoatencion2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion2.setText(tap2);
            retap2 = holder.textviewtipoatencion2.getText().toString();
        }

        if (tap3.equals("no contiene")) {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.viewtipoatencion3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion3.setText(tap3);
            retap3 = holder.textviewtipoatencion3.getText().toString();
        }

        if (tap4.equals("no contiene")) {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.viewtipoatencion4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion4.setText(tap4);
            retap4 = holder.textviewtipoatencion4.getText().toString();
        }

        if (tap5.equals("no contiene")) {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.viewtipoatencion5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion5.setText(tap5);
            retap5 = holder.textviewtipoatencion5.getText().toString();
        }

        holder.textviewtipoatencion1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.textview_tipoatencion1:

                        String txttap1 = textviewtipoatencion1.getText().toString();

                        BusinessFragment bsfragment = new BusinessFragment();
                           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                           bundle.putString("País", pais);
                           bundle.putString("Ciudad", ciudad);
                           bundle.putString("TipodeEmpresa", tipodeempresa);
                           bundle.putString("EmpresaUser", empresauser);
                           bundle.putString("Logo", logo+"");
                           bundle.putDouble("Latitude", lat);
                           bundle.putDouble("Longitude", lng);
                           bundle.putString("TipoAtencionSelected", txttap1);
                           bsfragment.setArguments(bundle);

                           FragmentManager FM = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                           FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();

                           FT.replace(R.id.fragment_container, bsfragment);
                           FT.addToBackStack(null);

                           FT.commit();

                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Tipo de atención: " + txttap1 + " " + pais, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        holder.textviewtipoatencion2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.textview_tipoatencion2:

                        String txttap2 = textviewtipoatencion2.getText().toString();

                        BusinessFragment bsfragment = new BusinessFragment();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("País", pais);
                        bundle.putString("Ciudad", ciudad);
                        bundle.putString("TipodeEmpresa", tipodeempresa);
                        bundle.putString("EmpresaUser", empresauser);
                        bundle.putString("Logo", logo+"");
                        bundle.putDouble("Latitude", lat);
                        bundle.putDouble("Longitude", lng);
                        bundle.putString("TipoAtencionSelected", txttap2);
                        bsfragment.setArguments(bundle);

                        FragmentManager FM = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();

                        FT.replace(R.id.fragment_container, bsfragment);
                        FT.addToBackStack(null);

                        FT.commit();

                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Tipo de atención: " + txttap2 + " " + ciudad, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        holder.textviewtipoatencion3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.textview_tipoatencion3:

                        String txttap3 = textviewtipoatencion3.getText().toString();

                        BusinessFragment bsfragment = new BusinessFragment();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("País", pais);
                        bundle.putString("Ciudad", ciudad);
                        bundle.putString("TipodeEmpresa", tipodeempresa);
                        bundle.putString("EmpresaUser", empresauser);
                        bundle.putString("Logo", logo+"");
                        bundle.putDouble("Latitude", lat);
                        bundle.putDouble("Longitude", lng);
                        bundle.putString("TipoAtencionSelected", txttap3);
                        bsfragment.setArguments(bundle);

                        FragmentManager FM = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();

                        FT.replace(R.id.fragment_container, bsfragment);
                        FT.addToBackStack(null);

                        FT.commit();

                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Tipo de atención: " + txttap2 + " " + ciudad, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        holder.textviewtipoatencion4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.textview_tipoatencion4:

                        String txttap4 = textviewtipoatencion4.getText().toString();

                        BusinessFragment bsfragment = new BusinessFragment();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("País", pais);
                        bundle.putString("Ciudad", ciudad);
                        bundle.putString("TipodeEmpresa", tipodeempresa);
                        bundle.putString("EmpresaUser", empresauser);
                        bundle.putString("Logo", logo+"");
                        bundle.putDouble("Latitude", lat);
                        bundle.putDouble("Longitude", lng);
                        bundle.putString("TipoAtencionSelected", txttap4);
                        bsfragment.setArguments(bundle);

                        FragmentManager FM = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();

                        FT.replace(R.id.fragment_container, bsfragment);
                        FT.addToBackStack(null);

                        FT.commit();

                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Tipo de atención: " + txttap2 + " " + ciudad, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        holder.textviewtipoatencion5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.textview_tipoatencion5:

                        String txttap5 = textviewtipoatencion5.getText().toString();

                        BusinessFragment bsfragment = new BusinessFragment();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("País", pais);
                        bundle.putString("Ciudad", ciudad);
                        bundle.putString("TipodeEmpresa", tipodeempresa);
                        bundle.putString("EmpresaUser", empresauser);
                        bundle.putString("Logo", logo+"");
                        bundle.putDouble("Latitude", lat);
                        bundle.putDouble("Longitude", lng);
                        bundle.putString("TipoAtencionSelected", txttap5);
                        bsfragment.setArguments(bundle);

                        FragmentManager FM = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();

                        FT.replace(R.id.fragment_container, bsfragment);
                        FT.addToBackStack(null);

                        FT.commit();

                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Tipo de atención: " + txttap2 + " " + ciudad, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return usuarios.size(); }

    public static class TipoAtencionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private Context context;
        private TextView textviewtipoatencion1, textviewtipoatencion2, textviewtipoatencion3,
                textviewtipoatencion4, textviewtipoatencion5;
        private View viewtipoatencion1, viewtipoatencion2, viewtipoatencion3, viewtipoatencion4, viewtipoatencion5;

        public TipoAtencionViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            context = v.getContext();
            textviewtipoatencion1 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion1);
            viewtipoatencion1 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion1);
            textviewtipoatencion2 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion2);
            viewtipoatencion2 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion2);
            textviewtipoatencion3 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion3);
            viewtipoatencion3 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion3);
            textviewtipoatencion4 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion4);
            viewtipoatencion4 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion4);
            textviewtipoatencion5 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion5);
            viewtipoatencion5 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion5);
        }

    }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, no sé cómo podría filtrar los datos...

Desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: tipo de atencion1 es telefonica pregunto para entender tu codigo??

Comment: Sí amigo, atencion1 es telefónica y atencion2 es VTR